# Compare y-values when having different x-values

Tags: python, compare

I try to calculate true positive and negative and false positive and negative. For this, I want to compare the y-values of the functions. Both have as x-value, time, but 1 has 600001 values in 1200 seconds and the other 5990. How can I compare the values of y at the same point in a graph?[The plot which I would like to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Cdd.png)

[image]

I can not make chunks, because 600001/5990 isn't an integer.
Does someone know where to start searching for an answer?

Comment: You want to compare visually or with computation?

Comment: With computation.

Answer (score 0):

The plot in your question is not interpolating between points it is maintaining the previous y value till a new one *comes-along* (it is showing step changes). If that plot visually makes sense to you then computationally you should follow the same process.

Comparing at time `now`

- find the point in `motion score mat` that has the highest x value not greater than `now`
- find the point in `Gross Motion` that has the highest x value not greater than `now`
- compare the y values of those two points.

Comment: How can I compare at time 'now'

Comment: ?? see the bullets in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put these values in a dataframe?

If you get a dataframe with the column headers `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, then you can do:

```py
# get equal values and reset index
df1 = df[df['x1'].isin(df['x2'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df[df['x2'].isin(df['x1'])].reset_index(drop=True)

# combine columns from each dataframe
# returns all values where x1 == x2 so you can compare y values
pd.concat(df1[['x1', 'y1']], df2[['x2', 'y2']])
```